# Laravel + git, contributors have different environment

Tags: php, git, laravel, dependencies, composer-php

Me and my coworker are trying to use local git repo for our Laravel project. 
I am using Ubuntu, with PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9, and he is using Debian with PHP 5.4.39.

When I pulled his committed version, I get an error when trying to run `composer update`:

```
user@ubuntu:/var/www/frontend$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Support\Arr' not found in /var/www/frontend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 182
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error   [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                            
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Support\Arr' not found in /var/www/frontend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 182
```

We have vendor folder on git, since not having it isn't an option for us.

I guess the problem is different php versions. Is there a way of setting up php version manually, so composer gets the right dependencies?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend working on a project with two different PHP releases. This will break things long-term. Simple example: If you run a `composer update` and add a library version that requires PHP 5.5 and up, this update will not run on your coworkers PHP. Always use the PHP version that is supposed to be used in production! Use it on all development machines as well - this will reduce unpleasant surprises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was probably this:

User checked in the project, including the vendor folder.

Later vendor somehow got added to .gitignore

Nobody noticed that new files were not being added to the repo and magic made sure everything still worked as it did :D

Answer (score 1):

you can set php version in composer.json file in require portion

```
"require": {
"php": ">=5.3.0",
},
```

Comment: I tried and got this error:

- This package requires php 5.4.39 but your PHP version (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9) does not satisfy that requirement.


This forces php version but does not solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I did not include >= part though

Comment: This requirement is NOT forcing and PHP version when it comes to resolving available libraries. It is a statement about the software requirement this `composer.json` belongs to, e.g. PHP code that uses PHP5.4 features should require at least PHP 5.4.0 here. Code that is compatible with PHP 5.3 would say 5.3.0 here - and remember that the 5.3 versions got several important bugfixes, so it is likely that the minimum will be one of (IIRC) 5.3.3, 5.3.9, 5.3.17 or 5.3.23 to address PHP versions with certain required bugfixes.

Comment: I thought it forces the version because it failed with the mentioned error even though I had a higher version installed. I did not understand that without ">=" it would require a specific version. I added ">=5.4" as you said since laravel 4.2 requires this version and it should work ok for all of us now.